# How to plot to the same file overwriting it?

Tags: gnuplot

I am fiddling with gnuplot. I am not able to output results to the terminal, but that's a different question.

I can plot into a png file. But each time I plot something I need to call `set output "plot.png"`.

Is there a setting that allows to overwrite the existing file?

Comment: No, there is no such option, but what's your problem with this, or what is your actual workflow? Are you working with a script, or do you want to dump a png when you are in interactive mode, etc?

Comment: @Christoph, I'm using interactive mode. It would be great to have a graphical terminal, but can't run it on my system. Basically I'm still learning and playing a lot with settings and it's a bit annoying to set output each time. Would you advice to run scripts instead of interactive mode?

Comment: For learning and trying you *must* have some kind of graphical terminal, otherwise it's very awkward in any case. Maybe editing a script, running that with gnuplot (possibly with some editor-plugin) and then looking at the output with some viewer can be more convenient.

Comment: Exactly :) For some reason I am not able to plot in x11 term on Mac. `set term` doesn't list x11 as an option.

Comment: What about `qt`, `wxt`, `aqua`?

Comment: Not in the list either. I think this has something to do with brew, it fails to install `gunplot --with-options`